# Android Source Code- writing custom services to startup at boot

Tags: android, android-source

I'm currently trying to learn how to write custom services and have them start up at boot, all in the Android Source code.

Could anyone point me to the right references (books, online articles, etc) that discuss this specific topic and as well as understanding AOSP/Android operating system in general?

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to write a custom Service you can [look at the docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

You'll want to learn about Activities and their Lifecycle [in the docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

And you'll want to learn about the Application fundamentals [in the docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Once you have an idea of how everything works fundamentally, there are tons of tutorials on the internet that will show you how to code specific things. A simple Google search will find you all of that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does a service have to belong to an application? I'm creating a service that is completely standalone.

Comment: @SangChanKim - Yes a service needs to be an application. You cannot create a basic system-level service or something similar. But you can create a very minimal app with no UI that just runs a background service.

Comment: @drschultz - the OP is contemplating modifying Android itself, not writing a 3rd party APK.